# Не читает на украинском языке

Tags: android, android-text-to-speech

На русском и на английском читает замечательно, а на украинском нет. 

Проверяется на версии android 4.2.2 (API 17), приложение компилируется под минимальную версию 4.1 (API 16)

Приложение: синтезатор речи Google 3.10.9 (в play market пишется что украинский поддерживается)


Почему может не читать на украинском?


**Код:**

```
topLocale = new Locale("uk_UA");

int result = textToSpeechTop.isLanguageAvailable(topLocale);

if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
      || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
  Log.i(TAG, "ukrainian locale not supported");
  return;
}

textToSpeechTop.setLanguage(topLocale);
textToSpeechTop.speak("з'їж ще цих м'яких французьких булок", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: Приложение https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en на устройстве установлено в последнее версии? Дополнительные файлы для Украинского скачаны и установлены?

Comment: @SergeMarkov Дополнительные файлы для Украинского скачаны и установлены?  - Какие ещё файлы?  
  - синтезатор речи Google в play market обновить нельзя

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wRTYvesXL2w8CHRywAR4IT_fh-Qv23lJL2f3Y7WMMe422BHw9UR0z97eETJ2jGm8taA=w1536-h759-rw Вот так примерно должно выглядеть

Comment: Странно но в настройках нету Украинского языка. Возможно версия android маленькая. Хотя планшет работает на Украинском

Comment: Украинский добавили с версии 3.11.12, но в ней же повысили `minSDK` до 19. А для API17 последняя доступная версия 3.10.9